# RPM cannot install package with error "unable to allocate memory for mutex"

Tags: linux, rpm

I'm currently working on a Yocto linux and trying to install something through RPM, But receive below error:

> root@qemux86-64:~# uname -a
>   Linux qemux86-64 3.19.2-yocto-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 25 11:11:53 IST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> root@qemux86-64:~# rpm -i net-snmp-5.7.3-5.1.i586.rpm
>
> rpmdb: BDB2034 unable to allocate memory for mutex; resize mutex region error: db_init:/home/iotg/poky/build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/rpm/5.4.14-r0/rpm-5.4.14/rpmdb/db3.c:1144: dbenv->open(12): Cannot allocate memory
>
> error: cannot open Packages(0) index: Cannot allocate memory(12)
>     DB: Berkeley DB 6.0.30: (January 23, 2014)
>
> error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm

I googled a while and tried to fix the problem by removing the __db.* temp files under /var/lib/rpm and do a "rpm --rebuilddb". The command ends without error.

But I still cannot install through rpm. What's worse, this time the process just hangs there without any output, until I kill -9 it.

Can anyone give me some clue?  Thanks.

Comment: can you try with adding `-ivh` flags ?

Comment: It's `rpmdb --rebuilddb` not `rpm`. But that is likely not your issue. You either have a corrupt `net-snmp-5.7.3-5.1.i586.rpm` or your `rpm` install itself is hosed. This question would be must better on *SuperUser* or *ServerFault*. You will likely receive much better help there.

Comment: Thanks David. I will ask the question on ServerFault and SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks juned. `-ivh` doesn't help, neither..